# Replace module function even before importing the module

Tags: python, import

I have a .py file which I want to execute, but can't change (because it's autogenerated by a 3rd party tool if you ask).
For example, it's just as follows:

```
hello()
```

Notice it doesn't import anything so you can't just simple import the module because there's no 'hello' name defined. How can I install/inject/setup necessary names in the module, before I import it?
Thanks!

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. `hello` must be a function inside that module, which you'd need to import.

Comment: To be clear:  you are saying that the 3rd party tool generates code which calls functions that do not exist?  That sounds like a bug in the 3rd party tool to me.

Comment: seems like you'd use: from <file> import <function> as <your preferred name> - where is that not working?

Comment: cdarke is exactly right. I can't modify that file, it's autogenerated.